# Bash injection from variable

Tags: bash, code-injection

I have the piece of code working on very remote server

```
ID=555
SLEEP_TIME=`ssh user@192.168.1.1 "cat /tmp/$ID.sleep; date >> /tmp/$ID.log"`
echo SLEEP_TIME $SLEEP_TIME
sleep $SLEEP_TIME
```

Yes, no quotes around $SLEEP_TIME. 
ssh user@192.168.1.1 works fine, without a password, by key. 
I see /tmp/555.log refreshing.
Sorry I've lost control on this remote server (on which above code is running by cron) making mistake in sshd config.
But I control server 192.168.1.1 and I can place whatever into /tmp/555.sleep = $SLEEP_TIME variable
How can I inject some code to $SLEEP_TIME variable forcing remote server to exec it?

This is 100% legal. Both servers belongs to my company. Please save me!
Indeed, I lost control on remote server becouse I used complex trick with port forwarding to access it, as it's IP is NATed few times.

Comment: can you ssh without password?

Comment: @Simonare I believe this is a question not related to the OPs question, and also, yes, it's pretty easy to setup ssh without password once `ssh-copy-id` was written.

Comment: @KamilCuk In my understanding, OP cannot reach 192.168.1.1 via ssh

Comment: @KamilCuk   No, I cant reach remote server with this script running on. I fully control 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I inject some code to $SLEEP_TIME variable forcing remote server to exec it?

You can't. *Shell expansion* happens once per command. *Shell expansion* does *shell parameter expansion* or *command substitution*. It happens at the same time. You can't do both. You can't expand a variable first and then expand it the second time to run a command substitution, because that's two expansions. From [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06).

(One could argue that *redirections* happen after *shell expansion* in bash per [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Syntax), but a simple test shows this is not true. Wonder if this is on purpose. But the Bash manual wasn't written for language layers. That's why it's a 'manual', not a 'specification'.)

Quoting is used to prohibit word splitting. The only thing you can do is to make your script error by passing unparsable argument to `sleep` or passing two or more arguments to sleep.

Also please don't use backticks ` ` for command substitution. They are deprecated, can't be nested, unreadable and look ugly. Use `$(...)`.

Comment: Backticks *can* be nested, but it's fugly.

Answer (score 0):

As `SLEEP_TIME` is just a variable and is not executed, I don't think there is a way to do that. So no, there is no way as far as I can see, sorry.